# Explain if block nesting

Tags: java

This is regarding some homework and I tried to make a range which is 10 to 40.
The code would accept two inputs within the range. The method will then check if both numbers are within the range and then if they are it would give me the product of both numbers, if not it is suppose to show me a message.

I have been working on this for quite a long time and I cant get it to work I am a complete beginner.

```
public class testing
{

    public static int computeProduct(int first , int second) 
    {     int max = 40;
        int min = 10;

        int total = first * second;
        if (min <= first) {
            if (first <= max) {
                if (min <= second) {
                    if (second <= max) {
                        total = first * second;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return total;

    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 10 to 40:");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter another number between 10 to 40:");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        int total = computeProduct(x, y);
        System.out.print("Product of x and y = " + total);



    }
}
```

Expected result is to show me if the numbers are not in range but it is not doing so currently.
It gives me the product of both numbers regardless whether it is in the range.

Comment: I think the other answer outlines a potential solution: in the else block simply print the message and return 0. Or just assign 0 to *total*.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
int total = first * second;
```

followed by an `if`, follewed by:

```
return total;
```

Meaning: every time when your `if` evaluates to `false`, your method simply returns the value that you assigned initially!

What you could do: have an `else` block that prints the error message. Or that throws an exception.

But ideally, you should *separate* concerns here. Meaning:

- write a method like `boolean inRange(int first, int second)`. That method returns `true` or `false`, depending on first / second matching your criteria
- if that method returns true, call `compute()`, otherwise print your message

In other words: your `compute()` method maybe shouldn't have that if block at all. Let that method compute the result, and have *another* method tell you whether you want to invoke `compute()` or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help could you emphasis on how to add the else block , due to the requirements of the question the same method has to do both functions. Could you give an example on how to add the else block. I tried your above suggestions but it required me to have a return statement at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A "ladder" built from `if`s behaves as a logical `and` relation. The first `if` passes when a condition applies, then the second `if` passes when both the previous condition applies and its own condition, and so on.
However for checking if something is off, violating *any* (even a single one) of the rules is enough, that is a logical `or` relation.

While it is not the best coding style, you could mechanically rewrite that structure into this via flipping the comparisions and dismantling the ladder:

```
public static int computeProduct(int first , int second) 
{
    int max = 40;
    int min = 10;

    if (first < min) {
        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
        return 0;
    }
    if (first > max) {
        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
        return 0;
    }
    if (second < min) {
        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
        return 0;
    }
    if (second > max) {
        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
        return 0;
    }

    return first*second;
}
```

This method displays the message and returns with `0` if the input is not valid, and returns the product if everything is fine.

Then it could become an actual logical `or`, which is denoted as `||` in Java:

```
public static int computeProduct(int first , int second) 
{
    int max = 40;
    int min = 10;

    if (first < min
          || first > max
          || second < min
          || second > max) {
        System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
        return 0;
    }

    return first*second;
}
```

Now as I think of it, there is nothing wrong with your original condition either, just the result has to be flipped: when the code reaches the innermost block, everything is fine, so that is the place where you could `return first*second;`. And if any of the `if` fails, you need the message and `return 0;`:

```
public static int computeProduct(int first , int second) 
{
    int max = 40;
    int min = 10;

    if (min <= first) {
        if (first <= max) {
            if (min <= second) {
                if (second <= max) {
                    return first*second;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
    return 0;
}
```

Now I am not so sure if this helps or not...

Comment: Don't your first two code samples just require that `first == min && second == min`?  Perhaps some of those `min`s should be `max`es.

Comment: thanks! it helps a lot I learnt a lot from it, I didn't think of flipping it around like that

Comment: yup @MikeSamuel I swapped some of them myself thanks for the input!

Comment: Upvoted to recognize the effort of putting down the if guard statements!

Comment: @MikeSamuel yes, it was a bit too much of copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

There you go :

```
public static int computeProduct(int first , int second) 
        {     int max = 40;
            int min = 10;
            if(first<=min || second<=min ||first>=max||second>=max)
            {
               System.out.println("Number is not in range, please try again");
               return 0; //or return whatever you like
             }
            return first *second ;

        }


    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 10 to 40:");
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter another number between 10 to 40:");
            int y = scanner.nextInt();

            int total = computeProduct(x, y);
            if(total!=0){
            System.out.print("Product of x and y = " + total);
             }
     else {
      System.out.print("cannot compute as numbers are not in range");
    }
}
```